# Does -OTMS group transfer to a different carbon easily?

Tags: organic-chemistry

In this organic transformation question, (https://imgur.com/a/nr0LHUm) I understand that the intermediate below gets formed, but why does it lead to the final product?
[image]

Comment: Provide a better reference than a link to imgur; this link to an *external reference* may stop being functional at any time. Instead, add title and authors of a text book, or primary publication (in the later case, a link/doi is a useful addition). If this means to redraw some of the reaction sequence, but you don't have access to a sketcher like ChemDraw, there is a [test page](https://chemdrawdirect.perkinelmer.cloud/js/sample/index.html) (with reduced functionality) to e.g. copy a screen photo. The drawing needn't be perfect, but share the relevant information in one spot here.

Answer (score 2):

It is well established [1](https://cdnsciencepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1139/v65-268) that trialkylsilyl groups can undergo alcoholysis i.e. swapping between alcohol groups both inter and intramolecularly and Me3Si-O is particularly labile because of its small steric bulk. Once this happens the cyanohydrin anion that is formed is very labile with respect to loss of cyanide to form the ketone.